# when taking backups using snapshot if the sstable gets compacted will nodetool snapshot hung?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1

We are taking backups using `nodetool` snapshots but I occasionally see that my script pauses  while taking a snapshot of a CF. Is this because when it is taking snapshot does the `sstables` got compacted to a different one  so it couldn't find that particular `sstable` on which it is taking snapshot so it pauses at that particular CF?

Answer (score 1):

Snapshots generated from `nodetool snapshot` are just hard links on the file system. I doubt very much if this is causing the pause.

I would recommend that you add some debugging to your script to see why its pausing and investigate that way. Many different variables could be at play here.

Comment: Hai markc when taking snapshot backups we are doing it keyspace basis , snapshot first flushes all in-memory writes to disk, then makes a hard link of the SSTable files for each keyspace, the doubt i am having is for suppose one of my table having two sstables A and B when data is flushed sstable 'C' is created, when the snapshot of A and B is completed and snapshot of C is underway, then  b and c merged to form D and c will no longer be present so what happens to snapshot in progress ?? I am not sure if  i am asking right question ?? does it makes sense ??

Comment: Hi, yes I see what you are saying. This is why I suggested to add more debug to your script to see what its doing when it pauses, you can use things like `bash -x` for shell scripts to give a verbose output